# Windows Embedded Compact - backward compatibility

Tags: compatibility, windows-embedded-compact

Would Windows CE 5.0 binaries be compatible on Windows Embedded Compact 7 and 8?

I've searched the Internet for a long time with no answers that are thorough or definite enough concerning the backward compatibility of these OSs.

Also I've tried to find the [ceappcompat app mentioned here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504713.aspx); it looked like it was supposed to be in the Platform Builder tools found in the installation of Windows Embedded Compact 7 x86, but it wasn't there.

Answer (score 2):

By way of experiment, I have found that Compact 7 is, in principle, backward compatible with respect to native applications. I was able to run x86 applications built against Windows CE 5.0 Standard SDK on a Compact 7 OS. However, Compact 2013 is a different story. As explained in the answer to [a similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ff2e18d-3db9-4b1e-a55f-2d7398c6c7da/windows-embedded-compact-2013-backward-compatibility-for-native-applications?forum=winembnatapp) on MSDN forum, existing Windows CE applications *must be recompiled* in order to run on Compact 2013. Reportedly, the breaking change in the new OS is the price paid for the ability to use the same Visual Studio 2012 tool chain for both desktop and Embedded Compact Windows targets.